# Bones won't join to mesh

Tags: mesh, bones

I am new to blender.  And have followed some youtube tutorials on creating and joining bones to an object (they make it look so easy!). It is a fishing rod FBX, I just want to add some bones to the rod so I can use dynamic bones in unity.

I have tried selecting the mesh and the bones and Ctrl P - trying:

- Armature deform with automatic weights
- Just selecting object

Nothing seems to happen, I have tried different things in "new projects" several time.  I sometimes also get an "loop in parents" error.

When I go into pose mode the bones are still separate to the mesh?

See screenshot below of the set up (the rod come in along the z axis, so I just left it there)

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

[image]

Thanks Josh,
That worked by  now the scale of the rod has increased by 100 and it has rotated 90 degrees along the y-axis?
Appreciate your help:)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your file the armature is child of the mesh, while it should be the opposite: select the armature and press Alt P (clear parent).

Then select the mesh FIRST, shift select the armature (mesh has to be highlighted orangy, armature yellow), then press Ctrl P with automatic weights.

In this way, in pose mode the bones will control the mesh.

Comment: Thank you, That worked but not it has multiplied the scale of the rod by 100 and rotated it 90 degrees along the y axis? I will put a screenshot in my post.

Comment: Before parenting apply rot and scale (Ctrl A) to both mesh and armature.

Comment: Thanks Josh,That didn't work but I fixed it after attaching the bones and it seems to work okay:). Thank you:)

Comment: Hello Josh, I just discovered that it only created about 3 breaks, any ideas why. I tried the first option here but it didn't seem to do anything. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15486/proper-way-of-attaching-bones-to-the-model.  Some screen shots are above.

Comment: I have given up and will get someone to do it using upwork.